# Content types with a field that get data from my custom table

Tags: nodes

as it said on the title, I've create a custom table named : writers (contains name,books..of writers)

To add a book, I've created also a content type that contains a form, with many textfields (book title, editor, number of pages..ect),now I want to have a list of writers (that are stored on my table : writers) to be sure that the book I'm adding is a book written by one of the writers I've on my table

I'm working on it for 2 days and I don't know how to do it, please if anyone can helps me it would be great

P.S. I don't want to let the user write the name of the writer on the form (content type) I want to let him choose on a list

Thank you

This is my book.module (to get an item to access to the form book):

```
<?php


function book_menu (){

$items['admin/books'] = array(
    'title' => 'books',
    'description' => 'books form',
    'title callback' => 'book_title_callback',
    'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'access arguments' => array('administer books'),
    'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('book_form')
);

  return $items;
 }

function book_permission(){
  return array(
   'administer books' => array(
   'title' => t('permissions to deal with books'),
   'description' => t('permissions to deal with books'),
 ),
  );
  }
```

and I have some functions..

Here we have the new function hook_update_7001 :

```
function book_update_7001(&$sandbox){
$info = field_info_field('field_data_field_writer'); //the select list on the content type

  $result = db_query("SELECT name_writer, uid FROM {writers} ");

  $res = $result->execute();
  $options = array();
   foreach($res as $sql){
    $options[] = array(
        'uid' => $sql-> uid,
        'name' => $sql-> name_writer,
        );
   }
$info['settings']['allowed_values'] = $options;
field_update_field($info);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try the [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module? If I understand your question correctly, you could create a content type `Writer` and add a reference field on your `Book` content type. This reference field can be used to select (i.e., use the 'Select list' widget) the appropriate `Writer` for your `Book`. No need to create a custom table yourself.

With permissions you can control who's allowed to create/edit/delete each of the content types.

Comment: Hi and thak you for helping me ^^ It's a good idea but I have to create a custom table for other reasons

Answer (score 0):

You can add new field to "Book" content type with type "Select list".
And then using [hook_update_n](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) add options to this field.

```
function mymodule_update_7001(&$sandbox) {
  // Get the field info
  $info = field_info_field('field_some_field');

  $options = array();
  //Make a select from your 'writers' table and prepare an array with writers.
  $query = db_select('writers');
  ...

  // Save the field
  $info['settings']['allowed_values'] = $options;
  field_update_field($info);
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew & thank you for you answer, It seems to be what I'm looking for, but where should I implement the hook_update ? In the book.module ?

Comment: Hi Pit. It is better to add your custom module for this

Comment: And for the field_info_field, should I set my custom table name ? (writers ?)

Comment: You should set there field name from your content type

Comment: I've just implement this function on the book.module but the select list that i've add on the content type doesn't show the writers list

Comment: could you please show your code?

Comment: Please Andrew check my question to see my code

Comment: It is very bad idea to place custom code in Drupal core modules. You had better create your own module. hook_update_n function should be placed in my_nodule.install file. And 'options' array should be filled like this $options[$sql-> name_writer] = $sql-> name_writer;

Comment: But i didn't put this function in a Drupal core, i put it on my custom module (book.module). I can't put it on the .install file because book is a content type i didn't create any table, i have just create book.module to put menu

Comment: Sorry. But drupal has 'book' module too

Comment: Yea that's right, i'm gonna change my module name

Comment: The problem is that I don't have "myModule.install"

Comment: you may add this file

Comment: This file will only contain the hook_update_7001 ?

Comment: yes, now we need only this function